# How to derive a formula from an algorithm

Tags: algorithms

I have a an algorithm for taking in any input number and deriving the output. Following these steps I can calculate $$f(x) = y$$ for any value of x, but it takes O(n^n) time to do manually. It appears to follow a pattern but not one that I can intuit easily.

Unfortunately I do not know where to even start for figuring out the actual function so that I can calculate the value more efficiently. Is there a way to take a data set of values from my algorithm and derive a function from it without knowing that it looks like a specific kind of curve?

In this specific instance the problem is

```
Find the sum of the digits of all the numbers from 1 to N (both ends included).

For N = 10 the sum is 1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+(1+0) = 46

For N = 11 the sum is 1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+(1+0)+(1+1) = 48

For N = 12 the sum is 1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+(1+0)+(1+1) +(1+2)= 51
```

and my naive algorithm loops through each number in the set, one by one.

I would appreciate the name of the technique used to derive a formula from a dataset like this, so that I can learn how to derive it myself

Comment: There is no general technique for converting a algorithm result to a formula.

Comment: Why would it take $O(n^n)$ time?!

Comment: I might have messed figuring out the big O notation of it, I am self taught and I have some gaps in the algorithm side of programming

Comment: @NiklasBäckström How do you go about seeing if your algorithm works with a non generic technique? Is it just experience with working with them?

Comment: Try to map your problem to others, try to simplify it by making assumptions, try to calculate certain values, there is a whole science to this.

Comment: If you only want an answer then try using wolfram alpha or [OEIS](http://oeis.org/A037123) where you can enter a squence for the first values.

Comment: This problem seems to not have an explicit form, so this time don't waste too much time on it.

Comment: That science to it is what I want to learn, do you know a place I could start? And roger on this specific problem

Comment: @AlexanderBurke Did you reach an answer to what that "science" is and some books ? I too hope to know how to write algorithms better mathematically.

Comment: I did not get any further on how to figure out the logic behind determining an equation

Comment: @AlexanderBurke I hope you post an answer whenever you find one. The closest I got to finding an answer is a book called Discrete Algorithmic Mathematics. I hope you find an answer soon as we both are self taught.